# How to use Twitter API to tweet to a specific audience. (ie. their new community feature)

Tags: api, twitter, twitter-api-v2

We use the Twitter API to post to our Twitter feed. Under the audience selection there is the option to choose "Everyone" or to choose a different audience, including "communities" that you are a part of. How do I post to twitter under one of those communities and not to the general feed when using the API?'

Looking at this, I am not seeing any parameter for it.
https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/manage-tweets/api-reference/post-tweets

See these images for more of an understanding of the options available in the tweet. It must be a single added parameter to the POST payload....if they offer this as an option. (I would think they would).

Any ideas?

[Image of the audience selection drop down when composing a tweet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zi5Yj.png)

[Image of the audiences available in the drop down menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zambY.png)

Answer (score 0):

This feature is not currently available in the Twitter API.

Comment: Thank you for your response Andy. Do you know if it is on the road map?

Comment: Yes, but since the Communities feature is relatively new, it is not top of the list at the moment.